# Unable to get into the GUI after installing a NVIDIA driver via apt - still can't get in after the driver uninstalled

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, ubuntu-gnome

My laptop has an Intel and a NVIDIA video card, when I installed I chose to use a NVIDIA close-sourced driver, and it works.

Today, after I installed `nvidia-driver-390` with apt, I can not get in the GUI after reboot.

After booting, the Ubuntu logo can be seen, but then the monitor went all-black, with an `_` underscore jumping at the left-top. After several seconds the monitor refreshes, the `_` disappeared, then the monitor refreshes again, then `_` comes back, then after several seconds the same procedure loops.

It is possible to get in to the terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+Fn`, but after several seconds I will be transferred back to the not-working GUI with that `_` jumping, so it is not possible to work on the terminal in init mode 5.

However, it is possible to work in the terminal in init mode 3. I `apt remove --purge`d everything starts with `nvidia`, rebooted, but everything is the same.

I tried to `startx` in the virtual terminal, but X just shut down immediately - maybe it is because I am in init mode 3?

I checked the Xorg log, there are several error lines:

```
(EE) open /dev/fb0: Permisssion denied 
...
(EE) modeset(GO): eglGetDisplay() failed
(EE) modeset(GO): glamor initialization failed
```

I removed the `quiet` grub option, and found that the system stuck at:

```
Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
```

There are another three maybe relevant operations:

1. After I installed the driver, I opened a 3D game to test before reboot, but the game complains that there are some OpenGL problem so it won't start.
2. Before installing from `apt`, I installed the `.run` driver released by NVIDIA co., but the installation failed for that `nvidia-drm` kernel module not found. I just tried run the `.run` with `--uninstall`, and it says there are no NVIDIA drivers currently installed.

Comment: You need to run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` after purging NVIDIA or otherwise no working video driver will be available.

Comment: @Raffa I can't test it anymore since i've got a brand new ubuntu = = it should be the problem.